# How to send information to the backend in React.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, flask, backend

I am very new to backend programming and I am quite confused when trying to figure out how to send data onClick to be stored in the backend. Right now the backend is a super simple flask server but my partner may be changing it to mySQL.
my application is a very simple react flashcard app that takes 10 questions from a trivia API and displays all 10 of them at once to the screen, each card with the question and answers choices, and the user can click on an answer choice to make a guess and if the guess is right, the card does a simple flip animation that shows the correct answer on the back. Now I am trying to send the data from the user's guess to the backend, so I would like to send the whole card, including the question, the incorrect answers, the correct answer, the answer that was guessed by the user, and whether it was right or wrong. here is an overview of every component in the project just so you can understand how it works:

my app.js file maps over the dictionary objects from my api and turns them into props. Here is the code in that file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import FlashcardList from "./FlashcardList"
import './app.css'
import axios from 'axios' // makes importing from api easy

export default function App() {
const [flashcards, setFlashcards] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
.then(res => {
    setFlashcards(res.data.results.map((questionItem, index) => { // mapping over api 
to get objects "questionItem" and the index of each one
        const answer = decodeString(questionItem.correct_answer) // setting the correct_answer objects from api to answer
        const options = [
            ...questionItem.incorrect_answers.map(a => decodeString(a)), answer // spreading incorrect_answers objects into an array with answer at the back to set all of them into options
        ]
        return {
            id: `&{index}-${Date.now()}`, // sets the id to the index from the api and the exact time to make sure its always unique
            question: decodeString(questionItem.question), // setting question objects from api to question
            answer: answer, // already defined above
            options: options.sort(() => Math.random() - .5) // sorting all the options randomly
        }
    }))
})
}, [])

function decodeString(str) {
const textArea = document.createElement('textarea')
textArea.innerHTML= str
return textArea.value // function brings all of our objects into this new element and decodes all of the encoded html
}
return (
<div className="container">
    <FlashcardList flashcards={flashcards} />
</div>
)
}
```

my flashcard.js file recieves the props from the app.js file and builds the front and back of the card, creates a useState to make the card flip, and a useState to calculate the height for each card. this is the code on the flashcard.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function Flashcard({ flashcard }) {     // recieving flashcard prop 
from our mapping in flashcardlist.js, each w a unique id

const MAX_TRIES = 4
const [incorrect, setIncorrect] = useState(false)
const [guess, setGuess] = useState(0)
const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false)
const [height, setHeight] = useState('initial') //sets the state for our initial 
height to be replaced by the max height

const frontEl = useRef() // lets us have a reference from the front and back through 
every rerendering of them
const backEl = useRef()

const handleUserPicksAnswer = (answer) => {
    if (answer === flashcard.answer) {
        setFlip(true)
        return "correct"
    }
    if (guess + 1 === MAX_TRIES) {
        setFlip(true)
    }

    setGuess(guess + 1)
    setIncorrect(true)
}

function setMaxHeight() {
const frontHeight = frontEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height //gives us 
dimensions of the rectangle but we only need the height
const backHeight = backEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height
setHeight(Math.max(frontHeight, backHeight, 100)) // sets the height (setHeight) to 
the maximum height of front or back but the minimum is 100px
}

useEffect(setMaxHeight, [flashcard.question, flashcard.answer, flashcard.options]) //anytime any of these change then the setMaxHeight will change
useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener('resize', setMaxHeight) //everytime we resize our browser, it 
sets the max height again
return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', setMaxHeight) //removes the 
eventlistener when component destroys itself
  }, [])


return (
<div 
className={`card ${flip ? 'flip' : ''}`} // if flip is true classname will be card 
and flip, if flip isnt true it will just be card
style={{ height: height }} //setting height to the variable height

    onClick={() => setFlip(!flip)} // click changes it from flip to non flip
>
<div className='front' ref={frontEl}>
    {flashcard.question}
    <div className='flashcard-options'>
        {flashcard.options.map(option => {
            return <div onClick={() => handleUserPicksAnswer(option)} 
className='flashcard-option'>{option}</div>
        })}
    </div>
</div> 
<div className='back' ref={backEl}>{flashcard.answer}</div>
</div>
 )
}
// setting the front to show the question and the answers by looping through the 
 options to make them each an option with a class name to style
// back shows the answer
```

my flashcardList.js file takes in the flashcards props from app.js and gives them each a unique id before passing it to flashcard.js to format the cards. here is that code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Flashcard from './Flashcard'

export default function FLashcardList({ flashcards }) {
// taking in the flashcards as destructured props so we dont have to make a props. 
variable
return (

// card-grid is a container so we can put all the cards in a grid to ensure they 
change in size proportionally to the size of the window //
<div className='card-grid'> 

{flashcards.map(flashcard => { // loops through the flashcards api and maps each one 
to flashcard

  return <Flashcard flashcard={flashcard} key={flashcard.id} /> // each flashcard is 
then passed down to the "Flashcard.js" component we created returned w a unique id
 })}
</div>
)
}
```

and then i have a app.css file that handles the complications of making the flip animation:

```
body {
background-color: #c8d0d2;
margin: 0;
}

.container {
max-width: 900px;
margin: 1rem 2rem;
}

.card-grid {
display: grid;
align-items: center;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr)); /* sets the cards to 
dynamically fit the page no matter how big it gets and to 200px minimum each card*/
gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
border-radius: .25rem;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
background-color: white;
transform-style: preserve-3d; /* to preserve our 3d elements so the card actually 
flips to the back instead of just rotating the front 180 deg */
/* height: 150px; /* this will be changed eventually so the height is automatically 
set by the size of the content text */
transition: 150ms; /* so we can see the flip animation by slowing it down */ 
cursor: pointer;
transform:perspective(1000px) /* to make the flip seem a little more 3d, less flat 
*/rotateY(var(--rotate-y, 0)) /* card will flip  to whatever we set the rotate-y 
variable in .card.flip */
translateY(var(--translate-y, 0));

}

.card:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6); /* makes the outline darker when hover */
--translate-y: -2px; /* moves the card up when hover */

}

.card.flip {
--rotate-y: 180deg;
}

.card .front {
left: 0;
}

.card .front,
.card .back {
position: absolute; /* so the front and back dont offset eachother */
padding: 1rem;
backface-visibility: hidden; /* makes it so anything facing backwards is hidden so 
the back of the card isnt showing on the front and the front isn't showing when the 
card is flipped to the back */ 
}

.card .back {
transform: rotateY(180deg); /* needs to be rotated because it's on the back so it 
will be flipped to the front and made right side up when flipped */
}

.flashcard-options {
margin-top: .5rem;

}

.flashcard-option {
margin-top: .25rem;
color: #555;
font-size: .75rem;
}

.flashcard-option:first-child {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

and then here is my super simple backend that just has the data for the 10 flashcards hard coded in there for now:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
resp = jsonify({"response_code":0,"results":[{"category":"Entertainment: 
Music","type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","question":"Who is the founder and 
leader of industrial rock band, &#039;Nine Inch Nails&#039;?","correct_answer":"Trent 
Reznor","incorrect_answers":["Marilyn Manson","Robin Finck","Josh Homme"]}, 
{"category":"Entertainment: 
Books","type":"multiple","difficulty":"hard","question":"What is Ron Weasley&#039;s 
middle name?","correct_answer":"Bilius","incorrect_answers": 
["Arthur","John","Dominic"]}, 
{"category":"Geography","type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","question":"Which of 
these is NOT an island that is part of the 
Philippines?","correct_answer":"Java","incorrect_answers": 
["Luzon","Mindanao","Palawan"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video 
Games","type":"boolean","difficulty":"easy","question":"The 2005 video game 
&quot;Call of Duty 2: Big Red One&quot; is not available on 
PC.","correct_answer":"True","incorrect_answers":["False"]}, 
{"category":"Vehicles","type":"boolean","difficulty":"easy","question":"The full 
English name of the car manufacturer BMW is Bavarian Motor 
Works","correct_answer":"True","incorrect_answers":["False"]}, 
{"category":"History","type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","question":"What year 
is considered to be the year that the British Empire 
ended?","correct_answer":"1997","incorrect_answers":["1986","1981","1971"]}, 
{"category":"Entertainment: Video 
Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","question":"What element does the 
Zinogre use in Monster Hunter?","correct_answer":"Thunder","incorrect_answers": 
["Ice","Fire","Water"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video 
Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"When was Left 4 Dead 2 
released?","correct_answer":"November 17, 2009","incorrect_answers":["May 3, 
2008","November 30, 2009","June 30, 2010"]},{"category":"Entertainment: 
Film","type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","question":"What is the make and model 
of the tour vehicles in &quot;Jurassic Park&quot; (1993)?","correct_answer":"1992 
Ford Explorer XLT","incorrect_answers":["1992 Toyota Land Cruiser","1992 Jeep 
Wrangler YJ Sahar","Mercedes M-Class"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Japanese Anime & 
Manga","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"What is the theme song of 
&quot;Neon Genesis Evangelion&quot;?","correct_answer":"A Cruel Angel&#039;s 
Thesis","incorrect_answers":["Stardust Crusaders","Requiem for a Dream","God 
Knows"]}]})
resp.status_code = 200
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept'
return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm a beginner and i appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

On the frontend you just need to send a request to an endpoint e.g. `guess` within the backend with all that information. You can of course use `axios` for that as well.

```js
try {
    // send request to backend and wait for the response
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/guess", {
        method: "POST",
        // Data will be serialized and sent as json
        data: JSON.stringify({
            guess: guess,
            correctAnswer: correctAnswer,
            // and whatever else you want to send
        }),
        // tell the server we're sending JSON
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
    if(!response.ok){
        // server returned a status code other than 200-299 --> something went wrong
    }
} catch (error) {
    // an error occured
}
```

On the backend you then need to handle this request by defining the `/guess` route, then parsing the JSON and then you have the values available in a Python dictionary.

```py
# import request object
from flask import request

# handle the /guess endpoint
@app.route("/guess", methods=["POST"])
def handle_guess():
    # parse the JSON request body that was created in the frontend
    data = request.get_json()
    # print the data which was sent from the frontend
    print(data["guess"])
    print(data["correctAnswer"])
    return
```

Comment: ok I have the front end request working but for the backend do I have to make that in a new file different from my main.py that provides the question. for example would i make a new file called "guess.py" with code similar to what you have and then run that file in a local host to see the data that I posted?

Comment: No, you just take my function (or my function adapted to what you actually want to do) and put it beneath the route for `/` (= function `index()`) which you already have. This is just another function in the same file. Flask will route the request for you so if it receives a request to `/` it calls your function `index()` and likewise if it receives a request to `/guess` it will call the method `handle_guess()`.

Comment: ok, thanks. understood. Now when I go to 127.0.0.1:5000/guess the browser displays "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.". do you know how to solve this? I tried to put the methods=["POST"] inside of my main app route as well but that didn't work

Comment: And you are also sending a POST request from the frontend to the `guess` endpoint? Those two must match. Don't put the `methods=["POST"]` in your `/` route. A normal request to load a website is always a `GET` request. You might wanna watch some tutorial like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA) to get your head around this.

Comment: It's working perfectly when i use webhook.site but i can't get the routing correct to post it to my own file. here is the frontend code:

Comment: nevermind it is too long to put in the comment